# Post bytes as a attachment to a Url using POST method without a file

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, post, httpwebrequest, http-post

I have a bytes array which I want to post to a url as a file attachment ,currently I am doing it with WebClient ,by writing those bytes to a file.

My requirement is,I want to avoid creating of a file from the bytes i have and directly post those bytes to the url as a attachment. Can anyone suggest me in this.

Comment: What about UploadData method of WebClient ?

Comment: @PavelKutakov  It won't do my need as I want to upload my bytes as a file to the url ,without writing my bytes to a file

Comment: Actually if you already have byte array, you can directly transfer it to UploadData method that accepts byte array as a parameter. You do not need to save it to the file. Sorry for being late.

Comment: @PavelKutakov thanks that u responsed and if i directly pass those bytes to upload data they are coming as a data but I want them to be a File containing my bytes.

Comment: Try to set Headers of the WebClient to specify content type. For example: webClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type","application/pdf");